# Why does this IIFE with Arrow function not execute?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious why this IIFE will run

```
(function() {console.log("hi")}());  //"hi"
```

But with an arrow function it does not run

```
(()=> console.log("hi")());
```

why is this an error?

```
(()=> {return console.log("hi")}());
```

but moving the parenthase now it works

```
(()=> {return console.log("hi")})();//"hi"
```

The parenthese, and the function keyword are changing the behavior of the IIFE executing, anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> (()=> console.log("hi")());
> ```

An IIFE consists of a function definition, immediately followed by `()`.

An arrow function definition consists of some parameters, followed by `=>`, followed by an expression.

`console.log(...)()` is an expression (meaning *call console.log as a function, then call its return value as a function*), so it is treated as part of the function definition (and thus the `()` do not **follow** the function definition, because they are part of it).

---

> The parenthese, and the function keyword are changing the behavior of the IFFY executing, anyone know why?

They are [a grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). They surround the function definition making the `()` which follow it explicitly **outside** the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for answering this.  I wasn't sure if I was asking it correctly, but you nailed the explanation.